# jQuery input mask with two different user inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

I'm trying to create an input mask, which collects two different values from the user. In the end the input mask should look like this:

[X.XXX$ for X years]

Where the X is an input by the user. Ist that possible? I've tried by using the jQuery Plugin inputmask and the code above:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.query').inputmask({
       mask: '9.999$ for 9?9 years',
       placeholder: '1.000$ for 2 years'
   });
});
```

The input mask doesn't work like I expected. It mixes the placeholder with the input values, what doesn't make sense to me. Can anybody help me with that issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using [this inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask)

The mask is getting into a funky state because there are some out-of-the-box definitions for `y` and `a`, which are being interpreted since they aren't being escaped.  If you want to look at all the other default definitions, then open up your debugger and take a look at `$.inputmask.defaults.definitions`, or just take a look at the script.

You can escape a definition in the mask by using `\\`

update your script to the following and you should be good to go.

[Here's a link to a fiddle if you want to experiment with it.](http://jsfiddle.net/2xgobr5v/)

```js
$('.query').inputmask({
   mask: '9.999$ for 9 \\ye\\ar',
   placeholder: 'X'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<input class='query' type='text' />
```